# Setting s3 endpoint for aws java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ceph

We are using `Resource` and `WritableResource` from below packages

```java
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.WritableResource;
```

Like

```java
String resourcePath = String.format("%s://%s", storageType, jmFolder + "/" + parentResourceIdentifier.getFolderStructureAWS() + "/" + fileNameDE);


Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(resourcePath);
log.info("Resource " + resource);

WritableResource writableResource = (WritableResource) resource;

// we getting stream from writable resource
```

We are using `OutputStream` to write files to S3 using AWS java SDK. We are not creating any s3 client but still it is working (I don't know How?).

Now we want to move it to use ceph storage but I am not able to give `endpoint` to aws java SDK. And I don;t want to create s3 client/ any kind of client. ( Actually I don;t want to change lots of code)

Comment: Have you considered [reading the docs](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#configuring-endpoints)? That would also explain how Spring recognizes the `s3://` URLs.

Comment: @Parsifal I am new to Java & this may be stupid question. Adding cloud.aws.s3.endpoint as environment variable also work, right?

Comment: I don't know if environment variables would work; it all depends on how Spring works (and as I don't use Spring, I'd simply be reading the docs to give an answer).